# Weekly data updates between JSON and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, database, transactions

I'm looking to develop an application which will at the end of the week synchronise the data between the web application's database and the data retrieved from JSON.

I understand the process of pulling data from JSON and I understand how to put that data into the SQL database; what i'm curious about is what is the most efficient or effective way of performing this process?

For example; table one stores 3 records of customers in the database; but at the end of the week; the JSON request shows that 1 customer has been deleted; so one customer will need to be deleted in the database.

Is it suitable to clear all the database entries and then re-insert them into the database with the updated fields? Or is there another way to achieve this effectively using PHP/MySQL? (i.e. placing two tables side by side somehow and comparing the two?)

Comment: can't you change the JSON feed to give only the changes? Let's say table1 needs to delete one entry with the id '1' . You can just change JSON feed to `[table1:[delete:['1']]] `

Comment: If you elaborate in an answer you might get yourself some points my friend :)